# Spanning single set of records through multiple pages

Tags: php, html, printing, report

I am doing some sort of lab test record collection but there is a feature that I am not sure how to implement.

There are multiple categories of tests such as FBC, HR etc. There are also multiple tests in these categories.
A person will be applied for multiple categories of tests and all the results are written together with a report being shown **for each category** of tests.
So FBC with all its tests will be having its own tests and so will HR.

The problem comes that this information should be shown with a specific format on **1 page**. If the tests are many, the records fill the other page (i have set a fixed height so it should fill the whole page but it can go more than the page size not less).

Is there a way to have some tests go to the other page but the header and footer and other repeating things should appear in both pages with the continuing of records from the previous page?

Its made in PHP and printing is being done through the browser too (HTML format printed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly what you're saying is you have a web layout with too much information to display in one page, and firstly you want to know how to put it onto a second page... and secondly how to re-use your site template... i.e. the headers and footers.

The headers and footers are easy, simply put your code for these into two separate files called:

```
header.inc.php
footer.inc.php
```

Then when you create a new PHP page just include them with:

```
include "header.inc.php";
// page specific content in between
include "footer.inc.php";
```

In the header file you could have your doctype, opening html tag, head section and opening body tag. Then in the footer you could just have the closing body and html tags, although you can also put other repetitive site features in these, such as copyright info, menu bars, etc.

For your other problem, you need to look into pagination.

Comment: i like your idea but the content was giving an issue. thanks for your accurate solution.